# Is it possible to comment out cells in Spyder?

Tags: python, comments, spyder

I am working in Spyder and was wondering if there is any way to comment out a whole block delimited by the common `#%%`. Consider the example below:

```py
#%% Block 1
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
# (other stuff)

#%% Block 2
```

Is it possible to comment out everything inside the Block 1 by any keybind shortcut (I'm working on Windows)?

By the way, I'm aware I can select all the lines and use `Ctrl + 4` or `Ctrl + 1` equivalently. I also checked [this document](http://e-callisto.org/cospar2018/SpyderKeyboardShortcutsEditor.pdf) with no success.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this have already been asked (couldn't find any useful post myself).

Comment: So you are trying to comment out blocks without having to select them?

Comment: @akaisteph7 I was thinking about something  like, while the cursor is on any line of the block, press some combination of keys to comment such block out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment, sorry.